# how to listen on port 25 with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, filter, spam

I'm basically trying to write a spam filter for incoming email on a mail server. I'd like to write a VB.NET program that can listen for any incoming mail on port 25 and then run my script on it and then pass it to the mail server running on a different port.

What do I need to do to have my program just sit and wait for a message to come in on port 25 and then react to it?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve the question yourself?

Comment: Tried to find any reference to listening on port 25 on the internet and came up empty.

Comment: Did you miss this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627031/listen-for-data-on-tcp-port-c-sharp

Comment: Did you miss the fact that I am trying to use vb.net not c#?

Comment: Vb.net and C# are the same under the hood, it is therefore easy to find online services to translate C# code to VB.net: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ In addition, because C# is a much more commonly used language, you will find many more examples / tutorials in C# than VB.net, it is therefore worthwhile spending the time to develop a facility at least for reading if not writing C#. Finally, if you are seeking help you will be more successful if you are patient and polite.

Comment: I was. Just returning sarcasm for a sarcastic response.

Comment: You'd probably better implement as some kind of filter plugin to your mail server instead of building all the SMTP stuff again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, as an example, is part of a socket listening service I modified from a tutorial a while ago in VB.NET. Basically, a socket listens for traffic on port 25 when the service is started, accepts a connection and then assigns that connection to a new thread, sends a response, and then closes the TCP connection.

```
Dim serverSocket As New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, "25")
Dim ipAddress As System.Net.IPAddress = System.Net.Dns.Resolve(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList(0)
Dim ipLocalEndPoint As New System.Net.IPEndPoint(IPAddress, 25)

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    Dim listenThread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf ListenForClients))
    listenThread.Start()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
End Sub

Private Sub ListenForClients()
    serverSocket = New TcpListener(ipLocalEndPoint)
    serverSocket.Start()
    While True
        Dim client As TcpClient = Me.serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient
        Dim clientThread As New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf HandleClientComm))
        clientThread.Start(client)
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub HandleClientComm(ByVal client As Object)
    Dim tcpClient As TcpClient = DirectCast(client, TcpClient)
    Dim clientStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream

    Dim message As Byte() = New Byte(4095) {}
    Dim bytesRead As Integer

    While True
        If (bytesRead = 0) Then
            Exit While
        End If
        Dim encoder As New asciiencoding()
        Dim serverResponse As String = "Response to send"
        'Response to send back to the testing client
        Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = encoding.ascii.getbytes(serverResponse)
        clientStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
    End While
    tcpClient.Close()
End Sub
```